# Find last modified file in a directory with white space

Tags: macos, perl, bash, find

I found and tweaked this script to find the most recently modified file in a directory recursively. It only breaks when there is a space in the directory name. Can anyone help me adjust the script so it will read directories with space also?s

```
for i in *; do

find $i -type f | perl -ne 'chomp(@files = <>); my $p = 9; foreach my $f (sort { (stat($a))[$p] <=> (stat($b))[$p] } @files) { print scalar localtime((stat($f))[$p]), "\t", $f, "\n" }' | tail -1

done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting fixes everything.

```
find "$i" -type f
```

Also, you don't need `tail`. Just swap `$a` and `$b` and exit after you print.

```
find $i -type f | perl -lne 'chomp(@files = <>); my $p = 9; foreach my $f (sort { (stat($b))[$p] <=> (stat($a))[$p] } @files) { print scalar localtime((stat($f))[$p]), "\t", $f; exit }'
```

And `-l` (letter "ell") appends newlines for you when printing.

**Edit:**

Actually there's no need for a loop at all:

```
find  -type f | perl -lne 'chomp(@files = <>); my $p = 9; @files = sort { (stat($b))[$p] <=> (stat($a))[$p] } @files; print scalar localtime((stat($files[0]))[$p]), "\t", $files[0]'
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I will certainly try it this way without a loop. I actually managed to fix the issue by adding IFS='\n' before the for loop.

Comment: Actually what I thought was my own solution doesn't work. Thank you again for your input, I'll try and get your suggestions to work.

Comment: Ok, thank you again! Adding the quotes gives me the result I need.

Answer (score 3):

Perl? you don't have bash and you like writing long lines of code? ;-)

```
find . -type f -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort -r | head -n1
```

Comment: OS X's find doesn't have a -printf option. You could use something like `find . -exec stat -f "%m %N" {} \; | sort -n | tail -1` though.

Comment: ah. yep, my original had similar use of exec. Believe `sort -r -n | head -1` would still be more efficient? (splitting hairs now!)

Answer (score 1):

Writing it all in Perl seems less messy

```
perl -MFile::Find -e 'find(sub{@f=((stat)[9],$File::Find::name) if -f && $f[0]<(stat)[9]},".");print "@f")'
```

Answer (score 0):

As you only deal with the current directory, you can do it with one command only:

```
find . -type f | perl -ne 'chomp(@files = <>); my $p = 9; foreach my $f (sort { (stat($a))[$p] <=> (stat($b))[$p] } @files) { print scalar localtime((stat($f))[$p]), "\t", $f, "\n" }' | tail -1
```

Answer (score 0):

By default the code below searches the subtree beneath the current working directory. You can also name on the command line one more more subtrees to search.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;

my($newest_mtime,$path);
sub remember_newest {
  return if -l || !-f _;
  my $mtime = (stat _)[9];
  ($newest_mtime,$path) = ($mtime,$File::Find::name)
    if !defined $newest_mtime || $mtime > $newest_mtime;
}

@ARGV = (".") unless @ARGV;
for (@ARGV) {
  if (-d) {
    find \&remember_newest, @ARGV;
  }
  else {
    warn "$0: $_ is not a directory.\n";
  }
}

if (defined $path) {
  print scalar(localtime $newest_mtime), "\t", $path, "\n";
}
else {
  warn "$0: no files processed.\n";
  exit 1;
}
```

As written, the code does not follow symbolic links. If you name a symlink on the command line, you will see output of

```
$ ./find-newest ~/link-to-directory
./find-newest: no files processed.
```

With *bash*, you have to add a trailing slash to force the dereference.

```
$ ./find-newest ~/link-to-directory/
Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 1970        hello-world
```